# Difference between erhalten, bekommen and vollbringen?

Tags: difference

Should I study all of them or I can just use any of them in different case? I am talking about other more verbs which has same meaning but differ in context ..

Comment: The more words you know, the better you will be able to a) express finer nuances and b) understand the meaning of texts. By “skipping” or using “one fits all verbs” you are just cutting yourself short.

Answer (score 3):

The main meaning of *erhalten* and *bekommen* is the same (to receive), they just have different niveaus of language (erhalten being the high-level and bekommen the mid-level one). There is a third word *kriegen* that should only be used in informal speech.
Both words, however, have a secondary meaning. *Erhalten* can mean to preserve, *bekommen* can mean to agree in the meaning of "that food agrees with me".

*Vollbringen* on the other hand has absolutely nothing to do with the other words, it means to accomplish.

Comment: Great answer! Could you please add a German examples for secondary meanings of both `erhalten` and `bekommen`?

Comment: Well, Tim, just look it up yourself. The *Duden* is usually quite useful. *erhalten* for instance is here: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erhalten